# Speed up spark dataframe task?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a dataframe loaded from csv, around 5.4 GB containing 210 columns
and approx 200000 rows.

I ran this function on the dataframe:

```
cnts = (df.select([countDistinct(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).first().asDict())
```

My system has 32GB ram, this task is too slow, shows around **13.5 hours** task time, is this normal ? 
Or, I'm doing something wrong, and we can speed it up a little ? 
This is a standalone installation of spark on windows server for POC.
[image]

[image: ca]

Comment: Did you use df.persist() before doing your request ? How much cores do you have on your machine ? 8 ? You can try to increase the number of partitions and activate the compression.

Comment: yes i did, and it shows 8 cores. how to activate the compression ?

Comment: see spark.rdd.compress parameter. Oh and do you use a distributed filesystem or a standard filesystem (i.e ext4, ntfs...)

Comment: Okay Thanks, i'll try it, and it's standard NTFS, will hdfs improve performance in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

try to persist the RDD and use MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level , if you don't have enough in memory ,it will try to write it back to DISK which will have performance benefits compared to recomputing the RDD.

If you are persisting it to disk use KYRO serialization , the default it binary format which is slow.